# Estimation of Input Signal to Obtain the Desired Output Signal for an Unknown Filter

Tags: filters, estimation, adaptive-filters, deconvolution, least-squares

Suppose $h(n)$ is a finite impulse response which is unknown. We can feed any input signal $x(n)$ into the system and observe the corresponding output signal $y(n)$.

From this, is it possible to estimate the input signal $x^*(n)$ which when passed through the filter gives the desired output signal $y^*(n)$ ?

I think a Least Mean Squares filter could be used here. Could anyone point out how one proceeds doing this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Short pointer: the technique that you're looking for is called *deconvolution* (or, for your case specifically, you're trying to do *system identification*). You are correct in that LMS is one way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Could you please review my answer? If it fits you, please mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most simple case, just to give intuition about the problem, it is really easy.

In the Frequency Domain:

$$ {Y}^{\ast} \left( \omega \right) = H \left( \omega \right) {X}^{\ast} \left( \omega \right) \Rightarrow {X}^{\ast} \left( \omega \right) = \frac{ {Y}^{\ast} \left( \omega \right) }{ H \left( \omega \right) } $$

Since $ {Y}^{\ast} \left( \omega \right) $ is known all needed is $ H \left( \omega \right) $.

Yet since we have access to a black box of $ H \left( \omega \right) $ we can set input of a known signal $ X \left( \omega \right) $ and have the output $ Y \left( \omega \right) $ which will give us $ H \left( \omega \right) $:

$$ Y \left( \omega \right) = H \left( \omega \right) X \left( \omega \right) \Rightarrow H \left( \omega \right) = \frac{ Y \left( \omega \right) }{ X \left( \omega \right) } $$

As others pointed out it is called Deconvolution and as you mentioned it can be done using Least Mean Square (LMS) Filter.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent resource for reading about deconvolution and its implementation is:

https://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/earthscienceandengineering/Public/lecture%20handout%2019Jan09.pdf